# Return a null value in an int[] array

Tags: java, arrays

I was recently asked this question and i couldn't come up with a solution. Having two int[] arrays, return an int[] array containing the overlapping range. We can assume that each array would contain only two elements. For example:

1. range1 = [1, 50], range2 = [50, 100], return [50]
2. range1 = [1, 100],  range2 = [50, 150], return [50, 100]
3. range1 = [0, 50], range2 = [100, 150], return null

The method signature provided was:

```
public static int[] range(int[] range1, int[] range2) { }
```

I got stuck on how to return a "null" in an int[] array.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

This was my approach:

```
    Arrays.sort(range1);
    Arrays.sort(range2);

    int[] range = new int[2];       

    if (range1[1] > range2[0]) {
        range[0] = range2[0];
        range[1] = range1[1];
    } else if (range1[1] == range2[0]) {
        range[0] = range1[1];
    } else if (range1[1] < range2[0]) {
        // Didn't know what to put here
    }

    return range;
```

Comment: "I got stuck"... Show us what you wrote so far. We're not going to do this for you

Comment: How to return a null `int[]` from the method: `return null;` Yes, it really is that simple.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, silly me! I guess i overthought and screwed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The start of the answer range is the highest of the two. The end is the least of the two. If the resulting start is larger than the resulting end, there is no overlap, and the result should be null:

```
public static int[] range(int[] range1, int[] range2) {
    int start = Math.max(range1[0], range2[0]);
    int end = Math.min(range1[1], range2[1]);
    if (start < end) {
        return new int[]{start, end};
    } else if (start == end) {
        return new int[]{start};
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to do the last test because if the fisrt condition or second conditon re not satisfied that will return empty range :

```
    int[] range = new int[2];       

    if (range1[1] > range2[0]) {
        range[0] = range2[0];
        range[1] = range1[1];
    } else if (range1[1] == range2[0]) {
        range[0] = range1[1];
    } 

return range;
```